# Passing parameter in MVC 3 to webform view (Aspx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I pass a parameter from MVC 3 controller to asp page

```
 VIEW passing data to DisplayResult in Controller

  @Html.ActionLink(ShowQueries.Query, "DisplayResult", new { Qry = ShowQueries.Query })



    CONTROLLER

    public ActionResult DisplayResult(String Qry)        
   {
       List<QuerySet> QueryToExecute = new List<QuerySet>();
       return View(QueryToExecute);
```

'QueryToExecute' is a query which needs to be executed against an external database on separate server. I was hoping that i can pass this as a parameter to a 'view' which is of type Webform (not razor).
This aspx page has required 'ado' connection info to connect to my external DB.....but i am not able to pass this parameter.

ASP PAGE

```
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Odbc" %>

<script runat="server">
sub Page_Load
        Dim dbconn, sql, dbcomm, dbread
        dbconn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=xxxx;Password=xxxx;User ID=xxxx;Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Port=xxxx;")
dbconn.Open()
        sql = "Select ID from TABLE1"
        dbcomm = New OleDbCommand(sql, dbconn)
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader() <%-- Call this method within oledbcommand--%>
```

Any ideas on how i can pass the parameter from controller above to paramter SQL in code above??

Answer (score 0):

Check your Route, have you define Qry as parameter in it. like 
http://yoursitename/display/{Qry}
let me know if you still not getting me.

Comment: like routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{Qry}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "DisplayResult", Qry = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

Comment: please edit your answer and add your comment in the answer for better readability ...

Comment: Thanks Satish. I updated the global.asax to include this route and I can see the controller passing the control to my DisplayResult.aspx view (non razor). So how do i pass the value to my ASPX page (Parameter SQL) above so that i can run it against another DB......i am new to asp.net as such still tryign to figure out nitty and gritty details. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Why are you running db code in the view?  This kind of eliminates the point of MVC.  It would be better to call db, get the data, and send the data you want to the view for it to be displayed.